# What is the main difference between Xen Hypervisor and XenServer

Tags: citrix, xen

I need to use Xen's SDK, do I need to install xen hypervisor? or XenServer.
I can't understand the difference between the two of them.

Answer (score 1):

### In Short Of

Xen Server is operating system built with CentOS DOM0 and Xen Hypervisor but Xen Hypervisor is software or application like KVM or Hyper-V.

### Details

What is Xen? [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen)

Same question -> [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/748144) [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1172887)

### Your Question

Xen SDK for Xen Server API Bindings